# Ошибка object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Имеется веб-приложение, написанное на Flask и Flask-SQLalchemy. В нем используется следующая модель:

```
class Event(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)
    owner = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(User.id))
    tags = db.Column(db.Text)
```

И есть функция, которая должна изменять значение одного из полей этой модели:

```
def change_event_tags(_id, new_tags):
    new_tags = "sample"
    event = Event.query.filter_by(id=_id).update(dict(tags=new_tags))
    db.session.commit()
```

Во время выполнения функция выбрасывает исключение `'Event' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'`. По какой причине это происходит и как это исправить?
Вот дебаг-вывод
[image: debug]

Comment: Добавьте к ошибке и трассу, тогда будет понятнее где упало

Comment: @gil9red Сделал.